# How can multiple groups of data be put in a single bar chart?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, seaborn

I have a simple DataFrame of nutrition values for each meal time:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
                 [ 0.0367354,  0.0484153 ,  0.0894831 , -0.131245 , -0.0961374, -0.049433  ,  0.142161      ,  0.0884946, 'breakfast'],
                 [-0.0603371, -0.00281495, -0.00470734,  0.100897 ,  0.0700709,  0.0259078 , -0.147854      , -0.0594319, 'lunch'    ],
                 [-0.0141466,  0.042048  ,  0.0411203 ,  0.0871926,  0.057405 , -0.00814915, -0.00340751    , -0.207868 , 'dinner'   ],
         ],
         columns=['calories', 'carbs'    , 'fat'      , 'fiber'   , 'protein' , 'salt'     , 'saturated-fat', 'sugar'   , 'mealtime' ]
)
```

How would a bar chart that features the bars/distributions of nutrient values for each meal group, a little like the following bar chart (where sex would correspond to meal group), be created?

[image]

I am imagining a command conceptually similar to the following (incorrect) command:

```
sns.barplot(df.columns.drop('mealtime'), df.drop('mealtime', axis=1).values, hue=df['mealtime'], data=df);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt your dataframe so it is easier to work with, in your case:

```py
temp = pd.melt(df, 'mealtime')
```

Output:

```py
    mealtime    variable    value
0   breakfast   calories     0.036735
1   lunch       calories    -0.060337
2   dinner      calories    -0.014147
3   breakfast   carbs        0.048415
4   lunch       carbs       -0.002815
```

Then plot:

```py
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
sns.barplot('variable', 'value', hue='mealtime', data=temp)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a million for the solution and for the detail on melt.

Comment: Anytime @BlandCorporation, `pd.melt` is a very handy method.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with `transpose` after setting the index

```
df.set_index('mealtime').T.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the solution. It's a nifty one-liner.